# Javascript Validation is not validating right

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build simple shopping cart where the user input books information and price, the javascript file would validate the input then after inputting several books info, the user would be able to view the order with books details and total price. The problem is that even if there was an error with the dataentry, the wrong information would be stored and hence I get a NaN for the total price.

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to perform client side navigation. What if someone has javascript disabled? (Blackberry phones). They will pass your validation, and boom, everything messes up.

As for your question, it would be easier to answer if you could have an isolated test case in a fiddle.

EDIT: As others said, it's simply because you aren't doing `correct = false` every time in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

In `function Validate()` you start off with `var correct = 'true'` and later have an if statement checking if it is still true, however there is no code before that `if` which could possibly change `var correct` to a value other than true. I'm guessing you forgot to add `correct = 'false'` in each of the ifs you have checking the variables.

Also, if you want `var correct` to be a boolean rather than a string, get rid of the "" around true.

Comment: The validation is not working at all now! I am posting my html file. Maybe someone would like to try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Price=document.getElementById('Price').value;
 if(isNaN(Price)||Price="")
     {alert("Please enter numbers only for price");
     correct = false;
  }
```